# How to write code for split method in Python 3.5?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, split

I just learned about the split method which slices the string at spaces and puts them into another list. I want to write the code for the split method using for loop.

I already tried to write a code for it which successfully slices the strings at the blank spaces in the string.

```
abc = 'With three words'
#x = abc.split()
x = list()
for i in range(len(abc)):
    if abc[i] == ' ':
     y = x.append(abc[:i])
     continue
print(x)
```

I want to know that how can I start the loop back from the place where it stopped and went into the if conditions. Like when I used the append method to slice the string abc and add into the list 'x'. The loop again starts from the beginning and I want to start the loop from that point itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stick as close to your code as possible you could try the following. The common way is just to use `str.split()`

changes I made for you:

- Keep track of the last white space found
- Do not only check for white spaces but also for the end of the string to get the last snippet.

---

```
abc = 'With three words'
#x = abc.split()
x = list()
last_white_space = 0
for i in range(len(abc)):
    if abc[i] == ' ' or i == len(abc) - 1:
     x.append(abc[last_white_space:i+1])
     last_white_space = i+1

print(x)
```

---

```
>>> ['With', 'three', 'words']
```

Comment: `last_white_space = i+1` and no need to `strip()`

Comment: Thanks !, instead of adding another variable to keep track of the iterations, I thought of manipulating the loop itself. My bad

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way to do `split`:-

```
abc = 'With three words'
x = list()
last_index = 0    
length = len(abc)-1   #To get length of string
for i in range(len(abc)):
    if i != length:
        if abc[i] == ' ':      
            x.append(abc[last_index:i])   
            last_index = i+1
    else:
        x.append(abc[last_index:length])

print(x)
```

I hope it may help you